# How to import Delphi function (that returns PAnsiChar) from DLL in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, dllimport

Function in Delphi is -

```
FuncName: PAnsiChar (stdcall)
```

I don't know the rest of the function code, cause i can't open the Dll.

And i tried to implement it to C# like this -

```
[DllImport("Lib2-2-1.dll", EntryPoint = "FuncName", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
        public static extern string FuncName();
```

when i'm trying to call this C# function in code - everything just closes without an Error, and the code stops executing. Could someone help me please and explain how to write it properly.

And another thing. I tried to open this Dll in DotPeek but it won't open and it says - Not supported, could someone please explain how can i view the code inside it.

Answer (score 1):

### **okey**

so, here is the answer, i [found it in this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041480/call-delphi-function-from-c-sharp)
here is the importing from Dll

```
[DllImport("Lib2-2-1.dll", EntryPoint = "FuncName", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
    public static extern IntPtr FuncName();
```

And this how to call it

```
IntPtr ptr = FuncName();
string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

Comment: How is this PAnsiChar value allocated? Does it need to be deallocated?

Comment: I'm sure you only [found](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/found) it, not [founded](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/founded) it.